# Autocorrelation Lag In Seconds Explanation?

Tags: autocorrelation

I am using a MatLab audio feature extraction toolbox (MIRToolbox), and I am in the process of cross correlating an onset curve (envelope).  I am aware of what the lag means when using Matlab's `xcorr` function since you normally pass in indices, but I am struggling to work out what the lag means when referred to in seconds on the x-axis.

According to the user manual, it has a minimum time of 0.2(s) and a maximum of 2(s) with onset envelopes.  Does this mean it only cross correlates for 2 seconds?  Its just that I have experimented with a 10(s), 30(s), and 3+(mins) edit of an audio file, and the plot is always showing 3 peaks, and looks more or less the same.

[image: Onset Detection]

[image: Autocorr]

Comment: Lag in seconds = lag in samples / sampling rate. That's the formula that explains what correlation in seconds boils down to. A minimum lag of 0.2(s) is still 0.2*sampling rate samples long. But I don't know what it means that there are three peaks consistently, unless you're autocorrelating, that would likely indicate the three harmonics (the first two if there is a peak at 0, but it looks like your cross correlation doesn't pass 0). This is surprising because usually the cross correlation goes from -time:+time.

Comment: I've edited my post to provide two plots - oss and autocorrelation of a 3 minute song. What I meant about the peaks being consistent is that I have a 10 second and 30 second edit of this same song and the autocorrelation plot doesn't seem to change. Please correct me if I am wrong, but does that mean autocorrelation function is only going to correlate the oss with the first 88200 samples `(2 secs * 44100)` of my 3 minute song?